# Executing Rails-using script using crontab

Tags: cron, rvm

I'm trying to run a ruby script that I can run just fine using Ruby from my home directory, but that fails using cron. The beginning of the script autocheck.rb looks like this:

```
require 'rubygems'
require 'mechanize'
require 'json'
require "active_record"

ActiveRecord::Base.establish_connection(
  :adapter => "postgresql",
  :encoding => "utf8",
  :database => "depot_development",
  :pool => "5",
  :username => "depot",
  :password => "fake_pwd")
```

The crontab looks like this:

```
*/15 08-17 * * 1-5 ruby /home/user/autocheck.rb
```

I checked the other entries here relating to cron and rvm (presuming that's the problem; I'm using rvm and ruby version 1.9.3) but I couldn't figure out the solution. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Replace `ruby` for the full path of `ruby` in your system (`/bin/ruby` or something like that)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

RVM has a command to setup schedules for you:

```
rvm cron command "*/15 08-17 * * 1-5" ruby /home/user/autocheck.rb
```

Comment: This didn't work, as written, but I eventually figured out one way to do it. I added this line to the beginning of the crontab shell, like so:     SHELL=/home/user/.rvm/bin/rvm-shell

Comment: yes that will work, with one important note - it will use default ruby might have unexpected error when there is no default. As for the failing command - please open RVM ticket for it => https://github.com/wayneeseguin/rvm/issues/